# Chef-client instantiated via json appending to array attribute, not replacing

Tags: chef-infra

Long story short, I have an array attribute, `foo`, that is set as follows:

```
echo '{"foo": ["bar"]}}}' | sudo chef-client -j /dev/stdin
```

The problem is on multiple calls of chef-client with different values for `bar`, instead of replacing the `foo` array, it simply appends to it.  How do I do a complete replace?

Answer (score 1):

So I ended up solving this by manually deleting the attributes on the chef-server side:

```
node.normal['foo'].each do |k|
          node.normal['foo'].delete(k)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules on attribute merges (the `-j` data gets merged with the stored values from the Chef Server) are wonky. If two arrays are at the same level and are subject to `deep_merge`, they get combined. Best off never using arrays in node attributes, will save you much trouble overall.